# in snowflake Pipes can be suspended and resumed ? True or False

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am confused as snowflake documentation says Snow pipes can be Paused and Resume. So Shall I take it as True.. Can someone help me to come with conclusion as Pause and Suspend are they similar in snowflake or they are different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, pipes can be paused:

```
 ALTER PIPE … SET PIPE_EXECUTION_PAUSED = true
```

and resumed:

```
ALTER PIPE … SET PIPE_EXECUTION_PAUSED = false
```

To verify that the pipe is running, we can query the `SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS` function again and verify that the pipe execution state is `RUNNING`.

Comment: Thanks Robert.. But still one thing to clarify the question says "Suspend" and not "Paused" so will it be "True" do we consider "Suspend" as "Paused". Kindly suggest

Comment: It's the same thing.